# Reactive Extensions Synchronous Subscription

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Can someone help me to do a Synchronous Subscription to an IObserver, so that the calling method will block until the subscription is complete. 
eg:

*Publisher*

```
public static class Publisher {
public static IObservable<string> NonBlocking()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(
            observable =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    observable.OnNext("a");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    observable.OnNext("b");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    observable.OnCompleted();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                });

                return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
            });
    }
```

}

*Subscriber*

```
public static class Subscriber{
public static bool Subscribe()
    {
        Publisher.NonBlocking().Subscribe((s) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }, () =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Complete");
        });
        // This will currently return true before the subscription is complete
        // I want to block and not Return until the Subscriber is Complete
        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use `System.Reactive.Threading.Task` for this:

Turn your observable into a task...

```
var source = Publisher.NonBlocking()
    .Do(
        (s) => Debug.WriteLines(x),
        ()  => Debug.WriteLine("Completed")
    )
    .LastOrDefault()
    .ToTask();
```

`Do(...).Subscribe()` is just like `Subscribe(...)`. So `Do` just adds some side-effects.

`LastOrDefault` is in there because the `Task` created by `ToTask` will wait only for the first item from the source `Observable`, and if no item is yielded it will fail (throw). So, `LastOrDefault` effectively causes the `Task` to wait until the source has completed, no matter what it yields.

So after we have a task, just wait on it:

```
task.Wait(); // blocking
```

Or use async / await:

```
await task; // non-blocking
```

## Edit:

Cory Nelson has made an excellent point:

In the latest version of C# and Visual Studio, you can actually `await` an `IObservable<T>`. This is a *very* cool feature, but it works in a slightly different manner than awaiting a `Task`.

When you await a task, it causes the task to run. If a single instance of a task is awaited multiple times, that task will only be executed once. Observables are slightly different. You can think of an observable as an asynchronous function with multiple return values... each time you subscribe to an observable, the observable/function executes. Therefore these two pieces of code have different meaning:

Awaiting an Observable:

```
// Console.WriteLine will be invoked twice.
var source = Observable.Return(0).Do(Console.WriteLine);
await source; // Subscribe
await source; // Subscribe
```

Awaiting an Observable via a Task:

```
// Console.WriteLine will be invoked once.
var source = Observable.Return(0).Do(Console.WriteLine);
var task = source.ToTask();
await task; // Subscribe
await task; // Just yield the task's result.
```

So, in essence, awaiting an Observable works like this:

```
// Console.WriteLine will be invoked twice.
var source = Observable.Return(0).Do(Console.WriteLine);
await source.ToTask(); // Subscribe
await source.ToTask(); // Subscribe
```

However, the `await observable` syntax does not work in Xamerin Studio (as of the time of this writing). If you are using Xamerin Studio, I would highly suggest that you use `ToTask` at the very last possible moment, to simulate the behavior of Visual Studio's `await observable` syntax.

Comment: Fantastic, didn't know about '.Do(..)' Looks like a LastOrDefaultAsync() method exists as well, so I can just do a .Wait() from that

Comment: You can directly `await` an `IObservable<>`. It will return the last item from the sequence.

Comment: @Lukie, before using LastOrDefaultAsync, you might have a look at my edits. converting an Observable to a Task too early can have profound effects on the reusability of your code. That being said, if you use LastOrDefaultAsync at the last possible moment, that's probably your best bet.